# A generic cache object

Tags: java, cache

I have a "generic" *cache* object:

```
public class Cache {

    private static final Map<Class, ICacheable> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static ICacheable getCacheableElement(Class cacheableElementClass, Object... params) {
        ICacheable cacheableElement = cacheMap.get(cacheableElementClass);
        if (cacheableElement == null) {
            cacheableElement = addIfNotExists(cacheableElementClass, params);
        }
        return cacheableElement;
    }

    private static ICacheable addIfNotExists(Class cacheableElementClass, Object... params) {
        ICacheable cacheableElementAdded;

        if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class)) {
            cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
        } else if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class)) {
            cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SymbolTable());
        } else {
            // Error!
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        cacheableElementAdded = cacheMap.get(cacheableElementClass);
        return cacheableElementAdded;
    }
}
```

The `Cache`'s responsibility is cache any kind of object. For that reason, I have the method's param `params` (I need to find a better name). `params` is for those objects which need a param for its creation. For example:

```
public class SourceCode implements ICacheable {

    private String sourceCode;
    public static final Character EOF = '#';

    public SourceCode(String sourceCode) {
        this.sourceCode = sourceCode.toUpperCase() + EOF;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `SourceCode` needs a `String` param (*sourceCode*) for its creation.

In some part of the code, I fill the `cacheMap`... In the case of the `SourceCode`:

```
cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
```

Here is my problem. As you can see, I create the `SourceCode` object with the first element of `params` array (remember the `varargs` in the above method's signature). IMHO, this is **not** a clean solution, because some objects will use the `params` array (`SourceCode`), and others won't use it.

**Is there a design pattern or a better way to refactoring this?**

---

**EDIT**: This is the solution I created:
[image]

As you can see, each object will have its own cache object (implementing `ICache` interface). Also,I have a `CacheFactory` which responsibility is create the cache object and returning it if it was already created.

Here is the code:

**ICache:**

```
public interface ICache {

    public Object getCacheableElement(Object... params);
}
```

**CacheFactory**

```
public class CacheFactory {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, ICache> caches = new HashMap<>();

    public static ICache createCache(Class cacheClass) {
        Boolean isICacheType = isICacheType(cacheClass);

        if (isICacheType) {
            if (caches.containsKey(cacheClass)) {
                return caches.get(cacheClass);
            } else {
                try {
                    ICache cache = (ICache) cacheClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
                    caches.put(cacheClass, cache);
                    return cache;
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    // TODO: Is this safe? If not, FIX IT!
                    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
                    throw new NullPointerException();
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Class \"%s\" not supported yet.",
                    cacheClass.getClass().getName()));
        }
    }

    private static Boolean isICacheType(Class cacheClass) {
        Boolean isICacheType = false;

        Class[] interfaces = cacheClass.getInterfaces();
        for (Class crtInterface : interfaces) {
            if (crtInterface.equals(ICache.class)) {
                isICacheType = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isICacheType;
    }
}
```

**SourceCodeCache**:

```
public class SourceCodeCache implements ICache {

    private SourceCode sourceCode = null;

    @Override
    public Object getCacheableElement(Object... params) {
        sourceCode = (sourceCode == null) ? new SourceCode((String) params[0]) : sourceCode;
        return sourceCode;
    }
}
```

**SymbolTableCache**:

```
public class SymbolTableCache implements ICache {

    private SymbolTable symbolTable;

    @Override
    public Object getCacheableElement(Object... params) {
        symbolTable = (symbolTable == null) ? new SymbolTable() : symbolTable;
        return symbolTable;
    }
}
```

Thanks to all of you for your recommendations and advices. It was a real pleasure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I have a "generic" cache object:

That's actually pretty non-generic. Especially, `Class` is a raw type.

```
private static final Map<Class, ICacheable> cacheMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Moreover, `static` mutable state is nearly always wrong. Use an instance variable and *if you really have to* a static instance of `Cache`.

It's also strange to restrict the keys and values like this. Compare to Guava [Cache](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/master/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html).

Especially restricting the values to some `ICacheable` sounds wrong.

> The Cache's responsibility is cache any kind of object.

As long as it's `ICacheable`???

> Here is my problem. As you can see, I create the SourceCode object with the first element of params array (remember the varargs in the above method's signature). IMO, this is not a clean solution, because some objects will use the params array (SourceCode), and others won't use it.

I'm rather lost what it's all about. If there's a `params` array, it sounds OK to me to use just a part of it. Not using it at all is a special case as it's like using a subarray of zero length.

Maybe your single cache should be multiple caches, one per class? See also [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html).

Comment: Hi maaartinus. You're right, especially regarding to restrict the values to `ICacheable` elements.
You said that Class is a raw type, and that's true. What would you use instead of this (thinking in create a generic solution). I didn't understand the explanation about `static` =/

Comment: @leonardo.manrique You could use `Class<? extends ICacheable>` or simply just `Class<?>`. The latter is about the same as raw `Class`, but produces no warnings. +++ [Static is evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7026563/581205). As a rule of thumb, the less mutable static state, the better. Sometimes, it's impractical, but then consider "postponing the `static` keyword", e.g., use a singleton instead of static fields.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of doing a whole lot of if-else over the supported constructor classes, you could use [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) to accomplish the construction of objects.

[`cacheableElementClass.getDeclaredConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) or [`getDeclaredConstructors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors--) to retrieve the constructor you want to invoke.

`Constructor.newInstance(params)` to create the constructor.

Sample code that might work:

```
try {
    // assuming the class only has one constructor that we can invoke
    Constructor<?> constructor = cacheableElementClass.getDeclaredConstructors[0];
    Object instance = constructor.newInstance(params);
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, instance);
} catch (... /*a whole lot of exceptions*/) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to be sure only a limited number of classes are supported, put the supported classes in a `HashSet` and check if the hashset contains the class you want to retrieve.

The throwing of the `NullPointerException` would be better of as an `IllegalArgumentException`, and don't forget to provide a helpful error message.

---

I find it a bit <strike>funny</strike> weird that if you call this:

```
SourceCode a = (SourceCode) Cache.getCacheableElement(SourceCode.class, "A");
SourceCode b = (SourceCode) Cache.getCacheableElement(SourceCode.class, "B");
```

The second call will return the `a` object, with `"A"` as the string value. This makes me wonder a bit about the general design and purpose of this code, it feels a bit strange.

---

This method could make use of generics to avoid having to typecast the result:

```
public static ICacheable getCacheableElement(Class cacheableElementClass, Object... params) {
```

Make that:

```
public static <T extends ICachable> T getCacheableElement(Class<T> cacheableElementClass, Object... params) {
```

Although I think the `ICachable` marker interface is useless, I'd recommend making it just:

```
public static <T> T getCacheableElement(Class<T> cacheableElementClass, Object... params) {
```

Comment: IMHO, this is too hacky for what you want to achieve. I'd maybe you it if there were tens of `cacheableElementClass`es, but even then it's not nice. And probably slower than the more direct solution I'm just about to figure out.... *Now I see that it may make sense. However, I'd probably avoid the whole problem by not using an universal all-classes-eating `Cache`.*

Answer (score 5):

Since your cache will be used application-wide, I think it should be thread-safe because otherwise the state of your cache might change halfway through an operation. To do this, add the `synchronized` keyword to your method signature. (I've never done thread-safety in java, only c#, so I might be a little off on the best practices about that in java.)

Also, the method named `getCacheableElement` might add an object into the cache, but it is impossible to know this without first checking the source code. I don't think a single method to do `add` *and* `get` is a good idea. Why not split in 2 different methods?

This cache implementation is not generic. Imagine I want to use your cache in my application, I wouldn't be able to do it since my classes wouldn't be part of your `if`,`else if`,`else`.

Throwing `NullPointerException` isn't a good idea. You might want to create a custom exception like `KeyNotFoundException`.

Comment: Hi TopinFrassi, I split the operations in two different methods thinking on taking further the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); it's perfectly reasonably your advice, because the principle talk about classes and not about methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I've answered the question before it's reached it final state, so I'm adding a review on this part:

```
    if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class)) {
        cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
    } else if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class)) {
        cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SymbolTable());
    } else {
        // Error!
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
```

It feels hacky and the problem seems to be the very existence of the universal all-classes-managing `Cache` and the existence of `ICacheable`. With not concentrating the code around this, you could have something like this

```
public SourceCode getSourceCode(String param0) {
    SourceCode result = sourceCodeCache.get(param0);
    if (result == null) {
        result = new SourceCode(param0);
        sourceCodeCache.put(param0, result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Above, I'm assuming that you need multiple elements per `cacheableElementClass`. Assuming I'm right, you get more type safety by

- returning `SourceCode` rather than `ICacheable`
- passing `String` rather than `Object...`

---

Assuming you really need just one element per class, then you should consider pre-creating all of them and use a [ClassToInstanceMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ClassToInstanceMap.html) to retrieve them in a type-safe manner.

---

If you can't pre-create *one stupid instance* per class, then reconsider the whole design. It *may* be right, but probably is not.

#### An afterthought

Maybe you need something completely different, namely a couple of singletons. Probably, there should be exactly one `SourceCode` and exactly one `SymbolTable` in your whole code. This is where the [singleton (anti-)pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Singleton_pattern) would help. A better alternative is to use [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), i.e., create all needed stuff somewhere in `main` and pass it to everyone needing it. It may get verbose, but it's pretty simple and perfectly testable. Once it gets complicated, use [Guice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guice) to manage your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Original answer is left below unaltered but my opinion has changed. The Java Class Library prefers `NullPointerException` to `IllegalArgumentException` when the element is required to be non-`null`. I think it's better to match their style here rather than be opinionated. Also, `NullPointerException` is more specific than `IllegalArgumentException`. Besides, you can use [`Objects.requireNonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) without importing any third party dependencies.

---

A small thing, in `addIfNotExists` you check if it's a few different types and if it's not you do `throw new NullPointerException();`.

```
if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
} else if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SymbolTable());
} else {
    // Error!
    throw new NullPointerException();
}
```

I don't like the use of `NullPointerException` here. If `cacheableElementClass` is null then it's fine (but I still don't like it). It seems better to throw a `InvalidArgumentException`. In addition, if it actually *was* null it would throw a "real" `NullPointerException` at the first if statement.

---

I recommend this, but it's ugly. I'd like it better if the `InvalidArgumentException` throwing was at the top, but it's a trivial change you can figure on your own (It makes sense for all preconditions to be at the top).

```
if (cacheableElementClass == null) {
    // Error!
    throw new NullPointerException();
}

if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
} else if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SymbolTable());
} else {
    // Error!
    throw new InvalidArgumentException();
}
```

The only reason I even *include* the manual throwing of `NullPointerException` is because I assume you do more stuff in the `// Error!` part, if you don't, remove it because it will do that on its own without you writing it in.

---

If you're using [`Preconditions`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java) library you can do this:

```
Preconditions.checkNotNull(cacheableElementClass);
// Preconditions.checkArgument(cacheableElementClass != null);
Preconditions.checkArgument(cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class) || cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class));

if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SourceCode.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SourceCode((String) params[0]));
} else if (cacheableElementClass.equals(SymbolTable.class)) {
    cacheMap.put(cacheableElementClass, new SymbolTable());
}
```

The commented out line is basically the same as the `checkNotNull` but it throws `InvalidArgumentException` which to me is just more informative in this case than `NullPointerException`, but it's up to you which you prefer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about `Preconditions`... I'll check it right now!

Comment: @Leonardo I added a link to the GitHub for the project (Guava), specifically the `Preconditions` class page. Guava is also useful for adding functional programming stuff that Java 8 added if you are stuck using a previous version for whatever reason. (Unfortunately you won't get lambda syntax...)